# Function to check Null

Tags: javascript

I created a function in Javascript but something should be wrong cause i haven't the awaiting result.
The idea is to test several variable. In case they are null i would replace with a blanck space.
Here is my code :

```
function chkNull(myObject) { 
   if (myObject == null){
       myObject = " ";
   }
}
```

And below i test with this :

```
var dOb = null;
chkNull(dOb);
```

I don't know what is wrong. If i test with if dOb == null below the var declaration, it is working.

Comment: Reassigning the value of the *function parameter* does not change the passed in argument.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is in no way a duplicate question. Just because another question is relevant, even if it's the cause of the problem, doesn't mean they're both doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a value

```js
function checkNull(value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return " ";
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And using it:

```js
let notNull = checkNull(maybeNull);
```

With your example:

```js
let dOb = null;
dob = checkNull(dOb);
```